# How can I assign a material from the asset browser to a specific material slot?

Tags: materials, asset-browser

I assigned several materials from an object to the Asset Browser, then tried to assign them to a new object, in a new file, that contains several material slots.

I assumed that if I selected the correct material slot for that object, then dragged the material from the asset browser  over the object, it would be assigned to that slot. However, it seems, no matter what I try, that the material is assigned to Slot 1.

Am I missing something or is this not yet possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender automatically detects the correct material slot depending on the face where the cursor is pointing. Each face has a material slot associated with it so you just have to aim the cursor on a face which is assigned to the material slot you want to replace.

[image]

Alternatively (for version 3.2 and above), if your material slot isn't used in any face on your object or the available faces are occluded in the viewport, you can drag the material into the slot in the Material properties.

[image]

Note the little tooltip that's displayed on top of the cursor tells you which slot and which material will be replaced.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Gorgious. That last option is exactly what I need. I looked in the documentation and couldn't find this. I guess, being a new feature, the documentation is a bit behind.

Comment: Well this is strange. The first method works fine - although I had to zoom in a lot as I'm working with MakeHuman models and materials for e.g. fingernails. But the second method does not work at all. I just get the ø symbol anywhere in the material slots area. I'm using Blender 3.0.1. Any ideas?

Comment: @Thailandian oh, snap ! I'm using one of the beta versions, I guess it's a feature that wasn't shipped with version 3.0. Sorry I think you'll have to either wait for the next release or use the beta version.

Comment: Thanks Gorgious - that clears that up. I can work with zooming in on the relevant faces so I'll wait for the next release.

Comment: As a matter of fact the 3.1 stable version just released today. I can't say for sure if this feature is part of it but you can try it out !

Comment: Just tried 3.1 and dropping onto slots is still not implemented. Did you notice any problems using this feature?

Comment: @Thailandian sorry for the mislead. I confirm that this feature is only available in 3.2 and onward.

Comment: That's OK - I have submitted an edit to your answer to that effect. It's still very useful overall so thanks again.